# imageView constraints on iPhone X does not work

Tags: imageview, constraints, iphone-x

The top constraint of the imageView is set to be 9px from the header but on iPhone X the constraint gets larger. See pictures: grey area between header section and top of image. Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Pics:

[Too much space between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSIP6.png)

[Proper 9px space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxN7Y.png)

Note:

- Picture is set to size 1080x1080

- Content mode is set to Aspekt Fill and tried also Scale to fill etc but none will work.

- ViewController consist of nested elements: View- SafeArea-ContentView- View-ImageView. Total constraint top 9px. These are nested inside another VC in a Scrollview element that is placed top:0px from header.

- Constraints set to superview top 0 in and in the headerVC to header top=0

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. Took away imageView top constraint to superView and Manually ctrl dragged a new constraint from the imageView up to the safe area.